# MAMP .htaccess loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing some troubles on my new MacBook, which I use for coding websites, locally. I've bought a license for MAMP Pro, cause I want to run locally. I've set up my .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://localhost:8888/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8888/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want the URL to be like `http://localhost:8888/index` instead of `http://localhost:8888/index.php`.

I've tried this before, when I was editing the code directly from the remote server, but now, whenever I'm trying to reach the webpage, .htaccess are creating some kind of loop.. Someone who know what to do?

EDIT:

Ok, I somehow got it to work (almost) with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8888/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But now, when I am entering a folder eg. `http://localhost:8888/new-folder/` then the URL changes to `localhost:8888/localhost:8888/new-folder/` and tells me that the requested URL wasn't found on the server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because this rule is wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://localhost:8888/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8888/$1 [L,R=301]
```

since `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches only the domain name part not `http://` OR port number.

It should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8888/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried the code above, but it still creates the damn loop.. :(

Comment: This is what I get from Safari: `There were too many redirects while http://localhost:8888/ was tampering`

Comment: Nevermind, your code works perfectly :) I forgot to delete the .htaccess-file inside the new folder :)

Comment: Oh that's great to know, I was testing the rules again and again on my localhost to figure out what can be wrong in such a simple rule :)